# Server (VPS) is going down when editing a bigger wordpress article! (?)

Tags: server, autosave

how is that possible?

I realise that nearly everytime when I edit a longer/ bigger wordpress article with much text my whole site is going down. Something by doing that cause an overloading of my VPS (2 cpu cores, 2gb ram). Normally it workes fine with the daily 4k users. But not if I am working on an bigger article (at night while there is no much real traffic anymore).

**So what could cause that issue?**

I guess maybe it is because of the permantly buffering/autosave by typing or anything like that?!

Thank you really much for any advice!

Comment: Please help me out with that! I cannot work in this way and the hosters support could not help me anymore :(

Comment: Really nobody :((( ???

Comment: Please, I still need your help !